# Get list of all files in azure blob folder

Tags: azure, .net-core

I am trying to get all files in a directory of a blob container. I am able to get all files in that whole container. But I am not able to specify a directory.

Here is my Code

```
    public async Task<IDictionary<string,DateTime>> GetBlobFiles(string directory="adf_exports")
    {
        IDictionary<string, DateTime> files = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
        try
        {
            var accountName = _configuration["StorageAccount"];
            var blobEndpoint = $"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net";
            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(blobEndpoint), credential);

            var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(_configuration["BlobContainer"] + "/" + directory);
            //var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(directory);
            var list = containerClient.GetBlobs();
            //var blobs = list.Where(b => Path.GetExtension(b.Name).Equals(".json"));
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                string name = item.Name;
                BlockBlobClient blockBlob = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(name);
                //using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Users\mbcrump\Downloads\test\" + name))
                //{
                //    blockBlob.DownloadTo(fileStream);
                //}
            }
            await foreach(BlobItem blob in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
            {
                files.Add(blob.Name, DateTime.Now);
            }
            return files;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return files;
        }
    }
```

It triggers the below error

> The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
> RequestId:b6449bde-d01e-003e-598b-a53f0f000000
> Time:2021-09-09T15:02:09.1881302Z Status: 400 (The requested URI does
> not represent any resource on the server.) ErrorCode: InvalidUri

But if we wont specify the directory and just the container like this

```
 var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(_configuration["BlobContainer"]);
```

it works without any issues. But returns all folders and files in that container.

But How can I specify a folder alone.

FYI I am using Managed Identity to access blob. Connection strings or access keys are restricted in our environment.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving that error because there are no specified resources in the mentioned subscription.

Here is the code that worked for me

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ViewBlobList
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("**Connection String**");
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("Container Name");
            Console.WriteLine("Listing blobs..."+"\n");
            // List all blobs in the container
            var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobs();
            foreach (BlobItem blobItem in blobs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(blobItem.Name);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

here is the output

[image]

For more information, you can refer [Quickstart: Azure Blob Storage library v12 - .NET | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#list-the-blobs-in-a-container).